# Creating a public property inside a class which is an instance of this class

Tags: c++, class, instance

I'm creating a class named `Circle` and needs a public property to access its 'parent' `Circle` instance. Thus I code it like this:

```
class Circle {
public:
...
    Circle parent;
...
}
```

But this gave me an error: `Incomplete type is not allowed`

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That cannot be done. Consider what the memory footprint of your type would be: a `Circle` contains a `Circle`, so it size cannot be smaller than the inner `Circle`, but that size is the same as the size of the outer `Circle`, reaching a contradiction.

Maybe you meant to store a *pointer* or *smart pointer*? That is allowed, since the size of the pointer is known by the compiler.

Comment: this is the standard design in this type of situation, e.g. in linked lists you keep pointers to your neighbours etc..

Answer (score 0):

You should define parent as a pointer to `Circle`:

```
Circle *parent;
```

Comment: I don't think the reference case makes much sense here (what would it be initialized to during construction of the first `Circle`?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah, the `&parent` would mean the address of `parent`.

Comment: It's an example of how it can *not* be done. Like David said, how would you want to construct the first Circle?

Comment: It's example of how we can avoid error `Incomplete type is not allowed`.

Comment: @flamingo: it will work with a pointer, as you said, but it will not work with a reference. Try it out.

Comment: Okay, I've understood it. Lol, sorry.